# HttpConnectionManagerParams.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(int) seems not working correctly

Tags: spring, httpclient, keep-alive, resttemplate

My application has to handel client http requests, communicate with some APIs, and return data to client. I declare a global RestTemplate for my application, as below:

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
            <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
            <property name="params">
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
                    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="20000" />
                    <property name="soTimeout" value="20000" />
                    <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="30" />
                    <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="500" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="requestFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <property name="httpClient" ref="httpClient" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

By setting `defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost`, I expect the number of simultaneous connections per host is **30**. But through my tests, it seems the actual number is at most **6** no matter how large I set `defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost`.

How I do my test:

- client side: sending about 20 requests to my web application simultaneously through browser (I tried FireFox and Chrome).
- server side: fetch the connection count by `netstat`

Questions:

- Question 1: Why is the number of simultaneous connections per host is not 30 as expected?
- Question 2: My application has to send out about 10 requests to one host per second. Each request lasts for 2 seconds. Then what's the appropriate value of `defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` should I set?

Answer (score 0):

After some more tests, I find my way to test mentioned in the question might be wrong. And `defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` works as expected.